# node js, npm install and window location jdk

Tags: node-java

I am installing the module ella on windows but I have a problem is that it does not work:

```
set JAVA_HOME =C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
npm install ella
```

And here is error:

```
npm WARN ella@1.5.1 No repository field.
checking user jdk
not found..
looking in user folder for jdk
looking for jdk in-> undefined/
undefined/
fs.js:808
return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'F:\projet  node\testItext
\node_modules\.staging\ella-3967a7fd\undefined'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:808:18)
at Object._search [as search] (F:\projet node\testItext\node_modules 
\.staging  \ella-3967a7fd\node_modules\file-tools\file-tools.js:77:20)
at search_jdk (F:\projet node\testItext\node_modules\.staging\ella-3967a7fd
\scripts\install.js:29:23)
at Array.look_user_folder (F:\projet node\testItext\node_modules\.staging
\ella-3967a7fd\scripts\install.js:91:12)
at install (F:\projet node\testItext\node_modules\.staging\ella-3967a7fd
\scripts\install.js:123:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\projet node\testItext\node_modules\.staging\ella-
3967a7fd\scripts\install.js:128:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
```

He would not see the jdk
thank you in advance